# Trying to send multiple values in a htmx request [Django] [HTMX]

Tags: django, payload, htmx

I'm encountering an issue when trying to send two values from the frontend to the backend using htmx. Here's my code:

```
{% include "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class='flex flex-col h-screen w-screen overflow-y-hidden'>
    {% include "sidebar.html" %}
    <div class='h-full flex items-center justify-center'>
        <div class='w-4/5 max-h-screen h-4/5 border border-black flex flex-col overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll mb-12'>
            <!-- Form Data -->
            {% for field, value in data.items %}
                <div class='w-full h-28 p-1 m-5 flex flex-col mx-24'>
                    <label for="{{ field }}" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{{ field }}</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="field" value="{{ field }}">
                    <input type="text" name="value" value="{{ value }}" 
                        class="editable-field bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-3/4 p-2.5" 
                        hx-trigger="blur" hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}' 
                        hx-post="{% url 'form' formId %}" 
                        hx-vals='{"field": "{{ field }}", "value": "{{ value }}"}'>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <!-- End form data  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I've tried using hx-vals and included quotes for those values, but the backend only receives the value, not the field. Here's the output in the backend:

```
<QueryDict: {'value': ['valiue']}>
valiue None
```

In my view, I'm attempting to retrieve both values using the following code:

```
def post(self, request, formId):
       print(request.POST)
       field = request.POST.get('field')
       value = request.POST.get('value')
       print(value, field)
```

I've tried using hx-vals, and changing the value of the input to the field property (removing it), and that works, but it's not a feasible solution for my scenario. I noticed that in the payload, the field is not present, leading me to believe that only the value of the input is being sent, and the hx-vals property is being ignored.

Is there a way to send both the field and value using htmx, or do I need to explore alternative approaches? Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: 1) Can you check if the html ouput is including the proper values? 2) Do you use latest version of htmx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
Use the hx-focusout and add a form tag, I avoided the form tag as I had a misconception that it required a button with the type of submit, here's the code which is working

```
{% include "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class='flex flex-col h-screen w-screen overflow-y-hidden'>
    {% include "sidebar.html" %}
    <div class='h-full flex items-center justify-center'>
        <div class='w-4/5 max-h-screen h-4/5 border border-black flex flex-col overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll mb-12'>
            <!--Form Data-->
            {% for field, value in data.items %}
                <div class='w-full h-28 p-1 m-5 flex flex-col mx-24'>
                    <form  hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}' hx-trigger="focusout" hx-post="{% url 'form' formId %}">
                        <label for="{{ field }}" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">{{ field }}</label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="field" value="{{ field }}">
                        <input type="text" name="value" value="{{ value }}" 
                        class="editable-field bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-3/4 p-2.5"  >
                    </form>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <!--End form data -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

the hx-blur only sends the value inside the input and not on the form, but triggering the form using focusout sends the data in both inputs to the backend

Answer (score 1):

When you specify parameter names in `hx-vals` that would otherwise exist in your form (as name attributes on inputs), the hx-vals will override the inputs.

Your example has two inputs, one called “field” and one called “value”.

“field” is hidden and never used (unless you have a form element wrapped around everything that I can’t see).

“value” specifies two `hx-vals` called “field” and “value”, thus overriding its own value. When you blur “value”, it will post only the hx-vals.

I assume you simply want to post both inputs while retaining the second input’s blur event as the trigger. You have several options:

#### Use the form, Luke

Remove `hx-vals` and wrap the inputs in a form element. HTMX will interpret any trigger from inside the form as a form submission, thus considering both fields in the post request.

This will post three parameters: The hidden “field”, the triggering “value”, and the hx-val “furthermore”:

```
<form>
    <label for="field">Important things:</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="field" name="field" value="This is the hidden value">
    <input type="text" name="value" value="This is the input value"
           hx-trigger="blur"
           hx-post="/some/where"
           hx-vals='{ "furthermore": "This is from hx-vals" }'>
</form>
```

#### Use `hx-include`

Replace `hx-vals` with something like `hx-include="previous [name='field']"`. This will make HTMX include the preceding input named “field” relative to the trigger element (the input named “value”).

This will post the same stuff as the above:

```
<div>
    <label for="field">Important things:</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="field" name="field" value="This is the hidden value">
    <input type="text" name="value" value="This is the input value"
           hx-trigger="blur"
           hx-post="/some/where"
           hx-include="previous [name='field']"
           hx-vals='{ "furthermore": "This is from hx-vals" }'>
</div>
```

#### Use dynamic JS in `hx-vals`

I mean… Don’t do this one… https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/

Btw, I believe your label’s `for` attribute does nothing, because it can only refer to element ids, not names (I’ve always found this ridiculous, but there may be a good reason, who knows).

Comment: Thanks for answering I already found a solution for this issue, it was to use hx-focusout with a form as using an hx trigger in an input will only give the value within that input and hx-vals were not overriding, I'll edit the post and add the code which fixed it